# Format date in XSLT issue

Tags: xslt

My source date is 2020-10-03T16:36:05.128Z. I want to convert it to CCYY-MM-DD in XSLT.
Any help will be appreciated.
I tried with different options but it is not working.

Comment: Isn't that simply `substring('2020-10-03T16:36:05.128Z', 1, 10)`? Or what result does the `CCYY` stand for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your source is actually a *dateTime*, not a *date*. In XSLT 2.0 or higher you can format it using:

```
format-dateTime($yourSource, '[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]')
```

In XSLT 1.0 (or any version) you can do simply:

```
substring($yourSource, 1, 10)
```

Comment: is there a way/tool/software to validate the logic?

Comment: See: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNvtBHf.